# How to get Numbers of the weeks of the Year if i have a month number?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem, that can't resolve by myself.

I have two fields - Month and Week. User should choose Month, and after that he should choose Week ( user can choose one week from the proposed to him values).

For example, user choose August. In the Week field should be available for him such values - 31 , 32, 33, 34, 35. If user choose June, in field Week - 22, 23, 24, 25, 26.

How can i find correct numbers of Weeks?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: seems like basic math to me.... or a hard coded array

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). *We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you*.

Comment: I think this is actually a valid question, because it's really about the Date API. I agree that asking for code is generally not a good thing, but this in particular seems like a useful topic for a lot of people.

Answer (score 0):

Start from January 1:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setMonth(0);
d.setDate(1);
d.setHours(12); // avoid daylight savings issues
d.setMinutes(0);
```

Then you can iterate through the year, creating a list of weeks in each month:

```
var weekNumber = 1; // or 0 if you want
var year = d.getFullYear();
var monthMap = {};

while (d.getFullYear() === year) {
  var weekList = monthMap[d.getMonth()];
  if (weekList)
    weekList.push(weekNumber);
  else
    weekList = [weekNumber];
  monthMap[d.getMonth()] = weekList;
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
  weekNumber++;
}
```

When that finishes, you'll have an object that looks like this:

```
{
  0: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  1: [5, 6, 7, 8],
  ...
}
```

(Those may not be right; I just made the numbers up here.)